# struct instantiation with "struct" keyword

Tags: c++, struct, keyword, declaration, instantiation

Suppose I declare a new C++ struct type:

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

Can I create a new instance of this struct type by:

```
my_struct foo;
```

or

```
struct my_struct foo;
```

If both work, is there any difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use either method.  The difference is that this form:

```
my_struct foo;
```

Is not legal in C, so you must use this form:

```
struct my_struct foo;
```

Which is supported in C++ for backwards compatibility with C.

Comment: Not only for backwards compatibility, the two are slightly different and there are cases where `struct` (or `class`) will be required. Arguably there are really few cases though.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Loki Astari: `struct test {}; void test() {} int main() { struct test t; }` without the `struct` (or `class`) keyword the identifier `test` inside `main` will refer to the function `test`, not the type `test`. Admittedly the issue there is with whoever had the *nice* idea of naming a type and a function with the same name, but in a language with namespaces, using declarations, using directives and argument dependent lookup[*] it is not always obvious what lookup will find. If the `struct` keyword is present, then lookup will skip over non-user defined classes.

Comment: [\*]: ADL does not affect this particular case, but it is yet another case of a feature that makes it hard to determine what is found by the compiler. So if I am going to *rant* about the complexity of lookup I might just throw it up there :)

Answer (score 3):

Both work. The main reason the second works is compatibility with C: In C the first doesn't work. As a result, `struct`s are typically `typedef`ed in C and there are two different kinds of names for `struct`s and `typedef`s.